# C# Declare a method from another class

Tags: c#, methods

Below is the problem I am having, part in particular has ** around it. I want to call the method "toolStripButton1_Click()" when my ImageViewer is opened. As it stands, when ImageViewer is opened, the image selected isn't opened with it. I've made the method public, hoping that that'll sort it out, I has not.

```
public partial class MediaPlayer : Form
{

    public ImageViewer iv;
    public AudioPlayer ap;
    public VideoPlayer vp;

    public MediaPlayer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ofdSelectMedia.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            switch(ofdSelectMedia.FilterIndex){
                **case 1: new ImageViewer().Show(); public void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);** 
                    break;
                case 2: new AudioPlayer().Show();
                    break;
                case 3: new VideoPlayer().Show();
                    break;
       }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Where is toolstripbutton1_Click declared?  All you are doing in your code example is declaring a new method signature.  You are not calling it as you think you are.

Comment: What do you **intend** to happen with the line `case 1: new ImageViewer().Show(); public void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);` - that isn't valid syntax, so the question becomes: what were you *trying* to do? did you intend to *call* that method? or...?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
somemethod();
}

void somemethod()
{
 //your code which u want to execute on click of a button
}
```

In case1 call the method `somemethod();` instead of calling an event.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code from the toolStripButton1_Click method to a function and call it from the case clause and from the toolStripButton1_Click handler.

```
private void DoIt()
{
    // The code from the toolStripButton1_Click handler
}    

private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoIt();
}



private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ofdSelectMedia.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

        switch(ofdSelectMedia.FilterIndex){
            case 1: new ImageViewer().Show(); 
                DoIt();
                break;
            case 2: new AudioPlayer().Show();
                break;
            case 3: new VideoPlayer().Show();
                break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is a method declaration, not a method call. Try

```
switch(ofdSelectMedia.FilterIndex){
    case 1: new ImageViewer().Show(); 
        toolStripButton1_Click(sender, e);
        break;
    case 2: new AudioPlayer().Show();
        break;
    case 3: new VideoPlayer().Show();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PerformClick() as shown below

```
public partial class MediaPlayer : Form
{

public ImageViewer iv;
public AudioPlayer ap;
public VideoPlayer vp;

public MediaPlayer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ofdSelectMedia.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

        switch(ofdSelectMedia.FilterIndex){
            case 1: 
                new ImageViewer().Show();
                toolStripButton1.PerformClick();
                break;
            case 2: new AudioPlayer().Show();
                break;
            case 3: new VideoPlayer().Show();
                break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It *sounds* like you intend something like:

```
case 1:
    var imgViewer = new ImageViewer();
    imgViewer.Show();
    imgViewer.toolStripButton1_Click(sender, e);
    break;
```

although personally, I'd refactor `ImageViewer` to have a `ShowImage` method, or similar, so that becomes:

```
case 1:
    var imgViewer = new ImageViewer()
    imgViewer.Show();
    imgViewer.ShowImage();
    break;
```

and your `ImageViewer` has:

```
public void ShowImage() {...}

void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ShowImage();
}
```